# How can I count and limit form submission?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that submits data to a mysql database. Once the form has been submitted it reloads and the user fills in the form and submits again over and over (They are being presented with different questions each time).

I want to limit the amount of times the user can submit the form to 3 before the user is headed to another page (results). I'm not sure how to go about achieving this. I have created a counter that logs each time a user submits the form in my database (code below) but I don't know what to do now. I am not using ajax. I'd really appreciate any help.

```
$sql="UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id=$id";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: Add a column that counts how many times they've accessed it, then set a conditional statement to see if that column has been accessed X-amount of times. I.e. `if((condition) >=3){...}`

Comment: Sessions might be another approach to look at

Comment: @Patrick Somewhat, but sessions can always get destroyed, so it's best that those values get hard-coded in their DB as a user logs in. But that is a good suggestion.

Comment: db won't help either if the form isn't behind some kind of login. destroying the session would also destroy the token that ties the DB count to the user.

Comment: I guess it really depends if the user is logged in or not. if the user is not logged in, there's no reliable way to make sure the column you're updating is the right user. which pretty much leaves sessions only as a non-reliable method. - EDIT - marc beat me to it.

Comment: @MarcB true...as outlined in my second comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The users are logged in and I have created a column that counts how many times they have submitted the form as I thought that would be a good start but but then what? Should I delete their counts everytime they have submitted the form three times? I did note mention that they can log back in and answers another three questions.

Comment: *"Should I delete their counts everytime they have submitted the form three times?"* - Yes, and only if they did answer all the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just another condition in your update:

```
$sql="UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id=$id AND counter < 4";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

But your goal is really not clear to me...